# Laravel 6.x right way to handle Pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel

I want to connect my `Customer` model with my `CustomerGroup` model in Laravel using Pivot tables.

I tried it with the following: (as reference I used https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/204838/how-to-use-custom-pivot-tables-in-laravel-6-x but I could have made something wrong)

I created the migration `customer_group_customer` and in the scheme I added following:

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger("customer_group_id");
$table->unsignedBigInteger("customer_id");
```

In the models `Customer` and `Customer_groups` I added a function. The function is like the following (this is the `Customer` model for example):

```php
 public function groups(){
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\CustomerGroup","customer_group_customer","customer_id","customer_group_id");
    }
```

Then I created a customer and a Group and then connected them manually with:

```php
        DB::table("customer_group_customer")->insert(["customer_group_id" => $group->id, "customer_id" => $customer->id]);
```

After that I fetched all Customers and saw that there aren't connected (via dd() I couldn't see any entry on groups or similar):

```
$customer = \App\Customer::create([]);
$group = \App\CustomerGroup::create(["name" => "hey"]);
DB::table("customer_group_customer")->insert(["customer_group_id" => $group->id, "customer_id" => $customer->id]);
dd(\App\Customer::first());
```

How do pivot tables get setup correctly?

And is there a better way to create a customer and assign it a group, without making it manually with the `DB` facade?

Comment: Please can you show the code you used to fetch the customers and their customer_groups?

Comment: @Rwd 
`
$customer = \App\Customer::create([]);
        $group = \App\CustomerGroup::create(["name" => "hey"]);

        DB::table("customer_group_customer")->insert(["customer_group_id" => $group->id, "customer_id" => $customer->id]);
        dd(\App\Customer::first());
`
thats how i did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your not seeing the `groups` relationship when you `dd()` the `Customer` is because it hasn't been loaded.

You can load the relationship by using `with()` when querying the model, or `load()` after you have an instance of the model, or simply by accessing the relationship as a property e.g. `$customer->groups`;

[Eloquent Eager loading documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

You can also use the relationship to `attach` different relations rather than using the `DB` facade to do it manually:

```
$customer = \App\Customer::create([]);
$group = \App\CustomerGroup::create(['name' => 'hey']);

$customer->groups()->attach($group);

dd($customer->groups);
```

[Attaching / Detaching Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Thx, you helped me a lot!